# JavaScript onclick display/hide div elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onclick, jquery-events

I am new to JavaScript and I need some help. I am developing a website in which I am having a button named "Add treatment notes".

1. If I click the "Add treatment notes" the corresponding two `<div>` should open and if the `<div>` is in open condition "Add treatment notes" button should change the text to "Hide treatment notes".

   ```
   <div id="divpopup"><button>Add treatment notes</button></div>
   ```
2. If "Hide treatment notes" is clicked,the two div's data should be in hidden.

   ```
   <td class="ir-shade4" colspan="2">
    <div id=irid1><p><em>If injured,mark location</em></p>
    <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/spotmarker.jpeg"/></div>
   </td>
   <td class="ir-shade3" colspan="2">
   <div id=irid2><p>Actions</p>
   <p><input id="ir-box" type="checkbox"/>01.Allowed to rest and returned to class</p>
   <p><input id="ir-box" type="checkbox"/>02.Contacted parents/guardians</p>
   <p><strong><em>Treatment given,or other notes</em></strong></p>
   <textarea class="textarea" name="description"></textarea>
   <p><input id="ir-box2" type="checkbox"/>No furthur action needed</p>
   </div>
   </td>
   ```

EDIT:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#divpopup").css("display", "none");
});

function addtreatment() {
  var hideValue = $("#irid1").val();
  var hideValue = $("#irid2").val();
  var newHideValue = 0;
    if (hideValue == 0) {
      newHideValue = 1;
      }
      else 
      {
        newHideValue = 0;
      }
    if (newHideValue == 0) {
      $("#divpopup").css("display", "none");
    }
    else 
    {
      $("#divpopup").css("display", "block");
    }
    $("#irid1").val(newHideValue);
    $("#irid2").val(newHideValue);
  
    return false;
  }
```

Please tell me how to implement this in my page.

Comment: Have you tried any thing beside the html code? If yes Please post the script you tried.

Comment: Kishor,i tried with the above code but it is not working,if i want o change some thing please tell me i want to make this function work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give button a id lets say

```
<button id="test">Add treatment notes</button>
```

Then

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#test").click(function(){
    $("#irid1").toggle();
    $("#irid2").toggle();
    if ($("#irid1").is(":visible")) {
        $("#test").html('Hide treatment notes');
    } else {
        $("#test").html('Show treatment notes');
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Hi,i followed with your code,toggle is not happening,whether i need to initialize in different function,please help me

Comment: I will check and revert sir

Comment: Ok Check my answer properly I updated and then just use and try it.

Comment: sir,it is working,one problem is that value is not changing while the div's are in hidden or vice versa.Can you tell me how to make that div should be in hidden while refreshing the page.Thanks for your extended help.

Comment: no it was a problem with my code,i corrected and working fine.Ur answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged your question with `jQuery`, you might want to look into jQuery's [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/), [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/), [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) functions.  That might get you started. When you have some code to share, feel free to come back and ask more detailed questions.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this

```
$('#divpopup').click(function()
 {
   $('.ir-shade4').toggle();
   $('.ir-shade3').toggle();
}
```

then use `$('#divpopup').text('Hide treatment notes');`

I will leave it for an exercise for yourself to put in an if statemetn to check what you should set the text to